# swatches not working in list page

Tags: magento-1.9, swatches, color-swatches

Am working in magento 1.9.2.3. The configurable color swatches is not working in list page of mobile view while it is working fine in list page of desktop view.It is also working well in details page of mobile view.Only in list page it is not working properly. Someone kindly help me to resolve this issue.